# Isomorphism between $R$-algebra $RG$ and $RG^{\ast}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, coalgebras

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $G$ be a finite abelian group. Consider a group ring $RG$ as an $R$-coalgebra. Is it true that $RG\simeq RG^{\ast}$ as an $R$-algebra? If the answer is true, please tell me the homomorphism that makes $RG\simeq RG^{\ast}$. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

No, not in general.  The dual algebra $RG^*$ is always canonically isomorphic to the ring of functions $R^G$ (with the algebra operations defined pointwise), but $RG$ may not be isomorphic to a product of copies of $R$.  For instance, if $R=\mathbb{F}_2$ and $G$ is cyclic of order $3$, then $RG$ is clearly not isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2^3$ since $RG$ contains a unit of order $3$ and $\mathbb{F}_2^3$ does not.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Is there any sufficient condition that will make $RG\simeq RG^{\ast}$ as an $R$-algebra? Note : $RG^{\ast}$ is an algebra dual of coalgebra $RG$ by a convolution product i.e. $f\ast g=\mu\circ (f\otimes g)\circ \Delta$, where $\mu$ and $\Delta$ is multiplication and comultiplication of $RG$.

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $R$ is an algebra over a field whose characteristic does not divide $|G|$ and which contains all $|G|$th roots of unity.  When $G$ is cyclic, this implies that $RG$ splits as a product of copies of $R$ by the Chinese remainder theorem, and then the general case follows by writing $G$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups.

Comment: What do you mean with "contains all $|G|$th roots of unity"?thank you

Comment: I mean that the polynomial $x^{|G|}-1$ splits over the field.